# Make windows button on keyboard default to search

Tags: windows-10, button-remapping

The Start Menu no longer holds any value to me, as its functionality is better reached in other ways.

- Whenever I use <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>, it still opens the vestigial Start Menu, I start typing, and the menu switches over to Search; I'd rather skip the middle man and have <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> immediately trigger search rather than the Start Menu.

Is there any direct, clean way to achieve this particular remapping, otherwise I'd be equally happy if it could trigger the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> screen instead?

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the button markup, but I'm not sure if the language overhaul was entirely necessary.

Comment: The only content I edited out was the subjective descriptions, with the only other removal being a redundancy _(subjective descriptions often serve to distract from what is actually being asked, muddling the question or answer, and since content remains on StackExchange for decades, I've always edited out subjective descriptions if they're not critical/relevant to what is being asked/answered - i.e. if the subjective description is removed, does the question/answer still hold true to the author's intent)_.  If you don't agree with the edit, you are able to revert it.

Comment: Have you tried [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Comment: @IshanShah I think you may have misunderstood what's being asked... Ease of Access [Accessibility] settings don't allow key-remapping

Comment: @JW0914 Looking into AutoHotKey as we speak. Remapping the windows key by itself while preserving its combinations was not a difficulty I foresaw, but should have.

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft's [Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051843/accessories-mouse-keyboard-center-download) to reassign keys as you like:

1. Download and install Mouse and Keyboard Center.
2. Connect the keyboard that you want to configure.
3. Start button → Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center
4. From the displayed list of key names, select the key you want to reassign.
5. In the command list of the key that you want to reassign, select a command.

Comment: Isn't Mouse and Keyboard Center limited to Microsoft hardware?

Comment: @gronostaj Indeed, after installing it it notifies me that no supported devices were detected. I am using a wireless USB Logitech Keyboard (from the now-defunct unifier range) with standard US international layout. Not exactly the most esoteric device in the world.
I'm sure for some use cases this is a good answer, but for me--not a solution.

Comment: @WeckarE. Have you tried Logitech's [application](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024361233) _(likely SetPoint or Options)_ for mice and keyboards _(I know for mice it allows button re-mapping)_, else [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) would probably be the recommended way to go.

Comment: the question didn't specify the brand as Logitech, so i assumed its generic or MS stuff :) no issues, happy that you managed to solve the issue with @JW0914 comment

Comment: @BasharAl-Abdulhadi I think this is MS exclusive, I doubt most generic would work.

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoHotKey (Thanks, JW0914; twice), I found a passable solution.

Solution works for Windows 10 (most scripts on Google don't!)

```
; -- This is where we block the normal key function (but not combinations) --
LWin & vk07::return
LWin::return
RWin & vk07::return
RWin::return

; -- This is where we override functionality --
LWin Up:: 
Send #s
```

Comment: I forgot to mention `WinKey`+`S` will also open search

Comment: @JW0914 Wow, yes. Now it is a perfect, clean solution. Wish I could give you credit somehow =/

Comment: he could answer the question and you select it as specific solution to Lgitech :)